# ANR thread wait

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a problem with my Java's understanding of the following problem. I have a game on Google Store and occasionally I'm getting ANR error on my developer console which points to onPause method within my custom Activity. I have a hard time reproducing the problem as well as understanding thread's intrinsic mechanisms. Stack call for this particular ANR looks like this (proguarded):

```
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
- waiting on <0x0f6bfc18> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:442)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:568)
  at xengine.XEngineActivity.onPause (XEngineActivity.java)
- locked <0x0f6bfc18> (a java.lang.Object)
  at android.app.Activity.performPause (Activity.java:8168)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause (Instrumentation.java:1508)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4725)
```

The part of the function where the problem occurs is pasted below, where `final Object threadsLock = new Object();` Can anyone spot what's wrong with it?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    synchronized(threadsLock) {
        if(gameState != GameState.INITIALIZATION) {
            gameState = isFinishing() ? GameState.FINISHED : GameState.PAUSED;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    threadsLock.wait();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO: ??
                }
            }
        }
    }
    audioMgr.pauseMusic();
    audioMgr.pause(true);
    inputMgr.onPause(); 
    if(isFinishing())
        audioMgr.release(); 
    else
        audioMgr.pauseMusic();
    glView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

EDIT:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    GameState gameState;
    boolean backButton;

    synchronized(xengine.threadsLock) {
        gameState = xengine.gameState;
        backButton = xengine.backButtonPressed;
    }

    if(backButton) {
        xengine.getScreen().onBackButtonPressed();
    }

    if(gameState == GameState.INITIALIZATION) {
        xengine.getScreen().onResume();
        synchronized(xengine.threadsLock) {
            xengine.gameState = GameState.RUNNING;
        }
        previousFrameTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    }
    else if(gameState == GameState.RUNNING) {
        gameRunning();
    } 
    else if(gameState == GameState.PAUSED) {
        gamePaused();
    } 
    else if(gameState == GameState.FINISHED) {
        gameFinished();         
    }

    if(backButton) {
        synchronized(xengine.threadsLock) {
            xengine.backButtonPressed = false;
        }
    }
}

private void gamePaused() {
    xengine.getScreen().onPause();
    xengine.shadersMgr.release();
    synchronized(xengine.threadsLock) {
        xengine.gameState = GameState.IDLE;
        xengine.threadsLock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a case of blocking the UI thread (Activity.onPause) - intermittent nature may have to do with other contenders for lock.

Comment: I really have no idea what the problem is about, threading is not my strength.

Comment: The ANR most likely is occurring because you are blocking on the main thread (`onPause` is on main thread) using `wait`- but a `wait` may be immediate - it may not - it all depends on the "other" code not shown here which `notify`ies the threadsLock object.

Comment: I see two usages of notifyAll on threadsLock in code. One is wihin onDrawFrame of a class derived from View and second also within onDrawFrame of the same class. There is some sort of state type of a machine implemented in onDrawFrame. I will share it above in the original question after EDIT.

Comment: I've pasted whole bodies of both functions. I don't know if it makes any difference with the ocurrence of the ANR problem, but I hope it will give the meaning to it. If there is anything else to be explained please let me know. Appreciate it

Comment: An ANR is thrown if your app has not responded to an input event for 5s !  In the above context the input event most likely was the user caused another app to enter foreground - resulting in your app enter `onPause`.  There is a `wait(timeout)` method which allows you to catch these cases and handle - use 1s e.g and 'break' - but could move the problem to the `onResume` if the gl thread is locked.  Note the  synchronization lock has been obtained so the code posted is not relevant - only the code which issues the "notify*" is relevant...

Comment: I really don't see why the `onPause` is waiting at all - grab the lock (which is working) set the state - and keep going.  Examine the remaining method calls for other deadlock potential as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is an old code that was rewritten from somewhere therefore I don't know why things are as they are. As for your answer, I don't understand the thread related jargon, so partly I don't know what you're talking about ex. "grab the lock". Did I understand correctly, there is no need for having this mechanism implemented at all and can be easily removed?

Comment: I've added the implementation of gamePaused which triggers notifyAll. There is a similar implementation of gameFinished which also notify's all in the same manner.